# Ubuntu Server Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS reboots instead of shutdown

Tags: command-line, server

I have a server which runs Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 LTS.
The problem is, instead of a proper shutdown, the server reboots itself, when using the "shutdown" command.

Comment: i tried "sudo shutdown -h" and "sudo systemctl poweroff" with the same result

Comment: While its not always rebooting, it is doing it most of the time, so that i have to shut it down twice

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

This will restart the computer instantly.
And if you another problem please post the terminal input in full

Comment: to shutdown & halt power (ie. real shutdown) use `sudo shutdown -h now`  -h=halt as opposed to -r=reboot.  -h (halt, or turn-off-power) does require the psu (power-supply) to turn off when signaled; most do it (but not all).

Comment: Well the problem is i don't want a reboot, it does sometime just restart instead of a proper shutdown...

Comment: @guiverc So does that mean it's a problem of the PSU, which doesn't turn off as expected?

Comment: if the PSU was designed to turn off yes (nearly all consumer grade & most of enterprise grade do it too).  some enterprise grade don't turn-off requiring a physical-button-press but those will NOT cause a reboot as you describe (the OS will have shutdown, drives powered down and machine will sit there idling).  A reboot as you describe is outside-of-norm (and could be a sign of [coming] component-failure maybe, but the component that failed could be the 'turn-off' bit & its as bad as it'll get)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo shutdown -P now
```

I tried -P for poweroff, and seems to work for some reason.

Comment: I don't know why, but after a CMOS reset, it seems to work now.